# start /wait - запуск приложений по очереди

Tags: dos, bat, cmd

есть приложение
запускаю его через пакетный файл (cmd ):

```
start /wait c:\Soft\12.exe
start /wait notepad
```

Всё работает нормально, НО если в приложении или каталоге присутствует пробел, то как быть?  Т.е. как запустить такое?

> start /wait c:\Work Soft\1 2.exe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ:

```
start /wait "заголовок окна" "c:\Work Soft\1 2.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
  start /wait "c:\Work Soft\1 2.exe"
```

Comment: Надо же! 5 поставивших UP'ы не знают команд DOS'а...  
Вы это сами пробовали, что написали?  
Я уже разобрался.  
В этом примере от [alexlz](http://hashcode.ru/users/352/alexlz)  
получиться вызов окна коммандного процессора с заголовком окна "c:\Work Soft\1 2.exe" и приложение НЕ ЗАПУСТИТСЯ!

Comment: Печально. Выгонят меня из археолухов.

Да, запускать сам не пробовал -- негде.

А, кстати, что такое "заголовок окна" в dos?

Comment: :)я хотел сказать - заголовок (титл) окна командного процессора ;)  
Это я по старой памяти так его называю...  
Просто сам тоже 2 часа потярял из-за этой фичи с ""  
(суб профиль юзера делаю)  
реализовал (пример):  
    start /wait "" "c:\Work Soft\1 2.exe"  
т.е. как-бы с пустышкой для титла.

Comment: Ну не dos это. cmd.exe -- это уже не dos. (в досе/мастдаях command.com). А у меня cmd.exe на start /? про заголовок окна ничего не говорит (wine 1.4). Когда эта хрень появилась?

Comment: @alexlz с первой же версии. Если есть кавычки - значит, заголовок окна.

Answer (score 0):

`Start /wait "c:\\\"work soft\"\\1\\2.exe"`
Как я понимаю тебе необходимы кавычки, тк пробельные символы в пути не есть хорошо. Не забудь их экранировать, скорее всего и \ тоже придется экранировать, как я написал

Comment: Что за муть с кавычкослешами?

Comment: Марк, Мне кажется и ваше сообщение тоже придётся экранировать....

Answer (score 0):

```
start /wait "заголовок окна" /D "c:\Work Soft" "1 2.exe"
```

Comment: Интересная идея.

Comment: Интересный вариант, но он тождественный моему, разница лишь в том, что у вас идёт разделение пути на путь к каталогу и сам запускаемый файл.

Comment: Соль в том, что в имени программы для start НЕЛЬЗЯ указывать пути. Пути к программе указываются отдельным ключом /D

Comment: Собственно в справке все это написано
Иначе путь берется от текущего + значения из %PATH%